# How to handle Daylight-saving time zone offset conversion for snapchat

Tags: c#, snapchat

I am trying to call Snapchat Marketing API for Ads stats with the end point through Postman

```
 https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/ads/<someId>/stats?granularity=DAY&start_time=2019-10-28T08:00:00Z&end_time=2019-11-26T08:00:00Z
```

Which is throwing error as

> "Unsupported Stats Query: Timeseries queries with DAY granularity
>   must have a start time that is the start of day (00:00:00) for the
>   account's timezone. This account's timezone  is: America/Los_Angeles",

But when I inspected on network tab in browser it taking start and End time with different timezone offsets as

**start_date = 2019-10-28T08:00:00Z (2019-10-28T00:00:00-08:00)**

**end_date = 2019-11-26T07:00:00Z (2019-11-26T00:00:00-07:00)**

And it working fine as well as through postman call. Is this happening because of Daylight-saving?. If Yes, How we can handle this using date time and timezone (region) or time offset?

Comment: *start time that is the start of day (00:00:00) for the account's timezone*

Comment: The timezone that is "displayed" doesn't matter.  The display is a string an not how the date is stored.  Dates are stored in memory using UTF time (a datetime object).  then is input and displayed depending on the computer regional settings which adjust the time base on the TimeZone Settings of the machine.

Comment: I am using **DateTimeOffset** object to store date and time for calling the API, everything is working fine with it. My problem is , Why API taking two different time zone offset .

Answer (score 0):

The documentation tells you you need to send in **00:00:00** for the time portion of the **start time** in the API call, so why not do that?

You can get just the date part of a DateTime object by calling the `Date` property on it.

Example code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"));
dt = dt.Date;
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"));
```

Output:

```
2019-11-26T07:23:48Z
2019-11-26T00:00:00Z
```